# Survey quiz questionnaire db design SQL show questi0n or choice based on previous answers django database

Tags: sql, database, django, survey

I have a survey app that I need to restrict a questions available answer choices based on a users previous answers.

To accomplish this I thought it would be a great idea to introduce a dependency table.

I feel I am almost there but I jsut cant figure out how to construct the correct query for the results I want or if I am approaching the problem the simplest way.

My tables are:

- User
- Question
- Choice
- Answer
- Dependency
- Choice_Dependencies (many to many through for Choice and Dependency)

A dependency references one question and one choice. Each dependency has a description field like "is male", therefore if question 1 is "are you male or female?" and question 1 has 2 choices, "male" choice_id=1, "female" choice_id=2. Then that Dependency record would reference question 1 and choice 1.

You can then relate that dependency to many choices.

Therefore if question 2 was "which of these things do you like most?" and the available choice records were makeup, skirts, cars, grease,

cars and grease would relate to the dependency for "is male" and the makeup and skirts  would relate to "is female"

I need to figure out how to write a query that gets all choices where each dependency is satisfied.

Another way I thought was to get any choices that did not satisfy and exclude those from the available choices. Maybe a NOT IN subquery?

Questions also relate to the choices they have. But I can take care of that part of the query.

This is a django app, but i dont care if i have to use raw sql. Below is my table structure as explained above in both SQL and django model syntax.

### SQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.auth_user (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    last_login timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    is_superuser boolean NOT NULL,
    username varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    is_staff boolean NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    date_joined timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE public.bny_question (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    section_id integer NOT NULL,
    input_type_id integer NOT NULL,
    "order" integer NOT NULL,
    text text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE public.bny_dependency (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    question_id integer,
    choice_id integer,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE public.bny_choice_dependencies (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    choice_id integer NOT NULL,
    dependency_id integer NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE public.bny_choice (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    question_id integer NOT NULL,
    text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    value varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    blurb text NOT NULL,
    "order" integer NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE public.bny_answer (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    question_id integer NOT NULL,
    choice_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

### Django

```
class Question(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey('Section')
    input_type = models.ForeignKey('Input_type')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def get_next(self):
        next = Question.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id)
        if next:
          return next[0]
        return None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.text)

class Dependency(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', null=True)
    choice = models.ForeignKey('Choice', null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "dependencies"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s [%s - %s]" % (self.description, self.question, self.choice)

class Choice(models.Model):    
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='choices')
    dependencies = models.ManyToManyField('Dependency', related_name='dependent_choices', null=True)    
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    blurb = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.value)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    choice = models.ForeignKey('Choice')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'question',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s" % (self.question, self.choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW, ok this really blew my mind, I've spent hours on this. If anyone knows a better way let me know.

I was able to get the exact results I wanted by using the following SQL Query which uses a NOT IN subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM public.bny_choice bc
WHERE bc.question_id = 6
  AND bc.id NOT IN
    ( SELECT bc1.id
     FROM public.bny_choice bc1
     INNER JOIN public.bny_question bq ON (bc1.question_id = bq.id)
     INNER JOIN public.bny_choice_dependencies bcd ON (bc1.id = bcd.choice_id)
     INNER JOIN public.bny_dependency bd ON (bcd.dependency_id = bd.id)
     INNER JOIN public.bny_question bq1 ON (bd.question_id = bq1.id)
     INNER JOIN public.bny_answer ba ON (bq1.id = ba.question_id)
     WHERE ba.user_id = 1
       AND ba.choice_id != bd.choice_id)
```

In order to do this in native djagno query syntax things got a little harder.

Django supports `NOT IN` by using `Choice.objects.exclude()` in conjunction with the `__in` operator in the filter...great...but Django does NOT support the `!=` operator.

Instead you can use Q objects prepended with a ~

`Choice.objects.filter(~Q(dependencies__choice = dependencies__question__answer__choice)`

This did not work because I think Django expects 1 item on either side of the equation to be a literal if you want to compare it to the value of something in the same table you have to use F objects so it now becomes...

`Choice.objects.filter(~Q(dependencies__choice = F('dependencies__question__answer__choice'))`

This works however it is not actually a true `!=` it actually equates to the following SQL...

```
SELECT •••
FROM "bny_choice"
INNER JOIN "bny_choice_dependencies" ON ("bny_choice"."id" = "bny_choice_dependencies"."choice_id")
INNER JOIN "bny_dependency" ON ("bny_choice_dependencies"."dependency_id" = "bny_dependency"."id")
INNER JOIN "bny_question" ON ("bny_dependency"."question_id" = "bny_question"."id")
INNER JOIN "bny_answer" ON ("bny_question"."id" = "bny_answer"."question_id")
WHERE NOT ("bny_choice"."id" IN
             (SELECT •••
              FROM "bny_choice" U0
              INNER JOIN "bny_choice_dependencies" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."choice_id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_dependency" U2 ON (U1."dependency_id" = U2."id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_question" U3 ON (U2."question_id" = U3."id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_answer" U4 ON (U3."id" = U4."question_id")
              WHERE U2."choice_id" = U4."choice_id"))
ORDER BY "bny_choice"."order" ASC
```

and using exclude in conjunction with `=`, yields the exact same SQL

```
Choice.objects.exclude(dependencies__choice = F('dependencies__question__answer__choice'))

SELECT •••
FROM "bny_choice"
INNER JOIN "bny_choice_dependencies" ON ("bny_choice"."id" = "bny_choice_dependencies"."choice_id")
INNER JOIN "bny_dependency" ON ("bny_choice_dependencies"."dependency_id" = "bny_dependency"."id")
INNER JOIN "bny_question" ON ("bny_dependency"."question_id" = "bny_question"."id")
INNER JOIN "bny_answer" ON ("bny_question"."id" = "bny_answer"."question_id")
WHERE NOT ("bny_choice"."id" IN
             (SELECT •••
              FROM "bny_choice" U0
              INNER JOIN "bny_choice_dependencies" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."choice_id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_dependency" U2 ON (U1."dependency_id" = U2."id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_question" U3 ON (U2."question_id" = U3."id")
              INNER JOIN "bny_answer" U4 ON (U3."id" = U4."question_id")
              WHERE U2."choice_id" = U4."choice_id"))
ORDER BY "bny_choice"."order" ASC
```

But I never give up so...

Thanks to asmoore82 I read on https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5763

> Similarly, you can almost approximate __ne with a hokey Q(__lt) |
>   Q(__gt) contraption.

The final Django result...

```
x = Choice.objects.filter(
        Q(dependencies__question__answer__user = self.user),
        Q(dependencies__choice__lt = F('dependencies__question__answer__choice')) | Q(dependencies__choice__gt = F('dependencies__question__answer__choice')) # Django workaround for not equals https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5763
    ).values('id')        
    self.choices = Choice.objects.filter(question = self.question).exclude(id__in=x)
```

This gives me the exact results I need.

Django spits out the following SQL

```
SELECT •••
FROM "bny_choice"
WHERE ("bny_choice"."question_id" = 6
       AND NOT ("bny_choice"."id" IN
                  (SELECT •••
                   FROM "bny_choice" U0
                   INNER JOIN "bny_choice_dependencies" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."choice_id")
                   INNER JOIN "bny_dependency" U2 ON (U1."dependency_id" = U2."id")
                   INNER JOIN "bny_question" U3 ON (U2."question_id" = U3."id")
                   INNER JOIN "bny_answer" U4 ON (U3."id" = U4."question_id")
                   WHERE (U4."user_id" = 1
                          AND (U2."choice_id" < U4."choice_id"
                               OR U2."choice_id" > U4."choice_id")))))
ORDER BY "bny_choice"."order" ASC
```

The query only takes 2.89ms and 1 query whereas before I was making the application check if each choice met the dependency and it took 163 queries in 123ms

Comment: I should apply the same functionality for my PHP project. What do you recommend: implementation in php side or in mysql side?